# Can someone explain this line of code to me please for treeview in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, treeview

`TreeList1.FocusedNodeChanged += treeList1_FocusedNodeChanged;`

Specifically what does the `+=` do?

Comment: Assigning an event handler *(`treeList1_FocusedNodeChanged`)* to `FocusedNodeChanged` event

Answer (score 2):

It is used to assign event handlers to events.

From MSDN:

> The += operator is also used to specify a method that will be called in response to an event; such methods are called event handlers. The use of the += operator in this context is referred to as subscribing to an event. For more information, see How to: Subscribe to and Unsubscribe from Events (C# Programming Guide). and Delegates (C# Programming Guide).

In your case, it assigns the `treeList1_FocusedNodeChanged` handler to the `FocusedNodeChanged` event of `TreeList1`.

**Additional Info:**

The function of the `+=` operator depends on the context. While in your case it is used to subscribe to an event, in other cases, it may be used for addition assignment.

Say for example, this code:

```
int x = 5;
x += 6; // This basically translates to x = x + 5, thus assigning x a value of 11.
```

Also, you can use lambda expressions instead of a separate method while subscribing to events:

```
TreeList1.FocusedNodeChanged += (s, e) => { // ... // };
```

The code in place of `// ... //` would be whatever there was in the separate event handler.

Comment: So treeList1_FocusedNodeChanged is what happens as a result of FocusedNodeChanged